# How to sum column values uniquely in 2way relation on unique accountID (check example)

Tags: sql, r, excel

Lets say I have a dataset about small loan shop and I want to find out how well are its loans covered by pledged securities. The thing is, I have multiple securities pledged for one loan, and one security pledged for multiple loans:

```
cAID cID cLoan sID sAmount
1   10  50   200 100    1100
2   11  50  1000 100    1100
3   12  60  1000 110     900
4   12  60  1000 120     300
5   14  80  1000 140    1200
6   15  90  1000 150     900
```

Amount of assigned security to the loan should not exceed the loan, and if security is higher than loan, and there is another loan backed by that security, remainer should be assigned to it.

Ideally I want it to end up like this:

```
cAIDa cIDa cLoanA sIDa sAmountA asignedSAmountA CoverageRatio
1    10   50    200  100     1100             200           1.0
2    11   50   1000  100     1100             900           0.9
3    12   60   1000  110      900            1000           1.0
4    12   60   1000  120      300            1000           1.0
5    14   80   1000  140     1200            1000           1.0
6    15   90   1000  150      900             900           0.9
```

How do I do generate these two other columns in either R or in Excel? Basically in the end I want unique client account ID and assigned sum of securities without oversumming securities. First raw loan is 200 (cLoanA) and security deposit (sAmountA) is 1100 so assigned security deposit is max of loan (asignedSAmountA) therefore 200, but the same security is used for next loan (notice same sIDa) and it was 1100, we subtracted 200 for first loan, it leaves us with 900 since the second row cLoanA is 1000 and is higher therefore we use whole amount of security deposit and have ratio of 0.9 which means part is unsecured. This is how I derive first couple numbers in asignedSAmountA and Coverage ratio.

My code in R:
    `

```
#example client AccountID
cAIDa <- c(10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15)
#example client AccountID
cAIDa <- c(10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15)
#example client ID
cIDa <- c(50, 50, 60, 60, 80, 90)
#example loan amount
cLoanA <- c(200, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)
#example security pledged ID
sIDa <- c(100, 100, 110, 120, 140, 150)
#example security pledged Amount
sAmountA <- c(1100,1100,900,300,1200, 900)

# generate initial data.frame 
portfolioOne <- data.frame(cAIDa,cIDa,cLoanA,sIDa,sAmountA)
portfolioOne

#assign security sum by unique account id
asignedSAmountA <- c(200, 900, 1200, 1200, 1000, 900)
portfolioTwo <- data.frame(cAIDa,cIDa,cLoanA,sIDa,sAmountA, asignedSAmountA)
ratio1 <- asignedSAmountA/portfolioOne$cLoanA
portfolioTwo$CoverageRatio <- ratio1
portfolioTwo
```

Comment: How do you get the asignedSAmountA ?

Comment: Hi, hope its a bit clearer now. Basically, I want to see how much each loan is backed, so I subtract loan by security with which it is backed.

Comment: Can you please write a formula to get that? I honestly can't figure out the numbers?

Comment: if(cLoanA => sAmountA, cLoanA, sAmountA) But the trick is how to use remainder for the next loan backed by that security, in this case, first raw loan is 200 and sAmountA is 1100 so asignedSAmountA is 200, but the same security is used for next loan (notice same sIDa) but because it was 1100, we subtracted 200, it leaves us with 900. This is how I derive first 2 numbers in asignedSAmountA. But I dont know how to get that by formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, now I understand what you want.

Here are the results I get from your original data:

```
    cAIDa  cIDa cLoanA  sIDa sAmountA asignedSAmountA  CoverageRatio
    10      50    200   100    1100         200             1.0
    11      50   1000   100    1100         900             0.9
    12      60   1000   110     900        1000             1.0
    12      60   1000   120     300        1000             1.0
    14      80   1000   140    1200        1000             1.0
    15      90   1000   150     900         900             0.9
```

Here is the VBA Macro I ran to get it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub AllocateSecurity()
    Dim colSec As Collection
    Dim dSec() As Double
    Dim dSecIndex() As Double
    Dim colLoan As Collection
    Dim dLoan() As Double
    Dim dLoanIndex() As Double
    Dim rSrc As Range, vSrc As Variant
    Dim vRes() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, d As Double, v As Variant
    Dim rDest As Range

Set rDest = Range("J1")

'Get Original Data
Set rSrc = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
    .Resize(columnsize:=5)
vSrc = rSrc

'Securities
Set colSec = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To UBound(vSrc)
    colSec.Add Item:=vSrc(i, 4), Key:=CStr(vSrc(i, 4))
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
ReDim dSec(1 To colSec.Count, 0 To 1)
ReDim dSecIndex(1 To colSec.Count)
For i = 1 To colSec.Count
    dSec(i, 0) = colSec(i)
    dSecIndex(i) = colSec(i)
    dSec(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(colSec(i), _
        Range(rSrc.Columns(4), rSrc.Columns(5)), 2, False)
Next i

'Loans
Set colLoan = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To UBound(vSrc)
    colLoan.Add Item:=vSrc(i, 1), Key:=CStr(vSrc(i, 1))
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
ReDim dLoan(1 To colLoan.Count, 0 To 1)
ReDim dLoanIndex(1 To colLoan.Count)
For i = 1 To colLoan.Count
    dLoan(i, 0) = colLoan(i)
    dLoanIndex(i) = colLoan(i)
    'covered amt
    dLoan(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(colLoan(i), _
        rSrc, 3, False)
Next i


'Set up Results Array
ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc), 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2) + 2)

'Headers
v = Array("cAIDa", "cIDa", "cLoanA", "sIDa", "sAmountA", "asignedSAmountA", "CoverageRatio")
For i = 0 To UBound(v)
    vRes(1, i + 1) = v(i)
Next i

With WorksheetFunction
For i = 2 To UBound(vSrc)
    For j = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
        vRes(i, j) = vSrc(i, j)
    Next j
    'LOAN = VSRC(I,1)
    'LOANAMT = DLOAN(.MATCH(LOAN,DLOANINDEX,0),1)
    'SEC = VSRC(I,4)
    'SECAMT = DSEC(.MATCH(SEC,DSECINDEX,0),1)
        'assSecamt
        vRes(i, 6) = .Min(dSec(.Match(vSrc(i, 4), dSecIndex, 0), 1), dLoan(.Match(vSrc(i, 1), dLoanIndex, 0), 1))
        'reduce loan and sec
        dLoan(.Match(vSrc(i, 1), dLoanIndex, 0), 1) = dLoan(.Match(vSrc(i, 1), dLoanIndex, 0), 1) - vRes(i, 6)
        dSec(.Match(vSrc(i, 4), dSecIndex, 0), 1) = dSec(.Match(vSrc(i, 4), dSecIndex, 0), 1) - vRes(i, 6)
Next i
End With

'coverage ratio:  1 - (uncovered amt/ orig amt)
'adjust assigned amt
With WorksheetFunction
For i = 2 To UBound(vRes)
    vRes(i, 7) = 1 - (dLoan(.Match(vRes(i, 1), dLoanIndex, 0), 1) / vRes(i, 3))
    vRes(i, 6) = vRes(i, 3) * vRes(i, 7)
Next i
End With

Set rDest = rDest.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes), columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
rDest.EntireColumn.Clear
rDest = vRes
rDest.Columns(7).NumberFormat = "0.0"
rDest.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe line 4 confuses You its a duplicate because there are two securities for 1 loan. If You take unique in column 1, You'll notice there is only 4000 assigned securities value, while there is 4200 of loan amount.

Comment: OK, I have changed my response in accordance with your comment, taking into account, I hope, all of the facts

Answer (score 1):

Reading in the sample dataset:

```
portfolioOne <- read.table(text="
  cAID cID cLoan sID sAmount
1   10  50   200 100    1100
2   11  50  1000 100    1100
3   12  60  1000 110     900
4   12  60  1000 120     300
5   14  80  1000 140    1200
6   15  90  1000 150     900
")
```

It appears from your example that we don't care from which specific security deposit the loan is covered. So let's make a column that details the total security deposits for an account `cID`. We can then cumulatively sum it through the loans to get the running balance, and therefore find which loans are covered/uncovered.

Note that I avoided double-counting amounts by using the `duplicated` function to find redundant rows. For the security deposits I excluded them by subset. For the loans, I set redundant entries to 0 so that the cumulative sum came out to the right length.

A `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(portfolioOne)
dat[, sTotal := sum(sAmount[!duplicated(sID)]), by = cID]
dat[, cLoanCum := cumsum({x <- cLoan; x[duplicated(cAID)] <- 0; x}), by = cID]
dat[, balance := sTotal - cLoanCum, by = cID]
dat[, assignedAmount := ifelse(balance >= 0, cLoan, pmax(0,cLoan + balance))]
dat[, CoverageRatio := assignedAmount / cLoan]

## delete intermediate columns if desired
dat[, c("sTotal","cLoanCum","balance") := NULL]
dat
   # cAID cID cLoan sID sAmount assignedAmount CoverageRatio
# 1:   10  50   200 100    1100            200           1.0
# 2:   11  50  1000 100    1100            900           0.9
# 3:   12  60  1000 110     900           1000           1.0
# 4:   12  60  1000 120     300           1000           1.0
# 5:   14  80  1000 140    1200           1000           1.0
# 6:   15  90  1000 150     900            900           0.9
```

A `plyr` solution:

```
library(plyr)
dat <- portfolioOne
dat <- ddply(dat, .(cID), mutate, 
    sTotal = sum(sAmount[!duplicated(sID)]),
    cLoanCum = cumsum({x <- cLoan; x[duplicated(cAID)] <- 0; x}),
    balance = sTotal - cLoanCum,
    assignedAmount = ifelse(balance >= 0, cLoan, pmax(0,cLoan + balance)),
    CoverageRatio = assignedAmount / cLoan
)
dat <- dat[,!(names(dat) %in% c("sTotal","cLoanCum","balance"))]
```

A solution using base R:

```
dat <- split(portfolioOne, portfolioOne$cID)
dat <- lapply(dat, within, {
    sTotal = sum(sAmount[!duplicated(sID)])
    cLoanCum = cumsum({x <- cLoan; x[duplicated(cAID)] <- 0; x})
    balance = sTotal - cLoanCum
    assignedAmount = ifelse(balance >= 0, cLoan, pmax(0,cLoan + balance))
    CoverageRatio = assignedAmount / cLoan
})
dat <- do.call(rbind, dat)
dat <- dat[,c(names(portfolioOne),"assignedAmount","CoverageRatio")]
```

Comment: Ok, this seems like nailing it, although I am not that familiar with data.table, I will have to learn it. Thank You.

Comment: I added `plyr` and base R solutions as well. If this answer works for you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark below the upvote/downvote arrows.

Comment: Thank You Blue Magister, @Blue Magister sorry for late response.